# How to reformat the date WITHIN a text file C#

Tags: c#

I'm writing a piece of code that takes in an access log and cleans it. Removes all data that i don't need and gives me out a clean version. I've cleaned it from redunadant data but i need to re-format the date which is one of the fields inside of the text file. (Below is the cleaned text file thus far)

[image]

I had initially planned on splitting it by '/' and then putting the 3 elements of the date into an array (day, month, year) and re-arranging so that the date was in american format - however this then breaks the file path by '/' and i don't want that.

Below is my code so far, any help or ideas would be much appreciated!

enter code here

```
  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(newFileName);
        string line;

        string personalIdentifier = new string(fileName.Take(4).ToArray());
        string gender = fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 5, 1);
        string classification = fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 8, 2);
        string text = string.Empty;

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] cleanArray;
            cleanArray = new string[7];

            var result = line.Split('"')
                 .Select((element, index) => index % 2 == 0
                  ? element.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  : new string[] { element })
                 .SelectMany(element => element).ToList();

            cleanArray[0] = personalIdentifier;
            cleanArray[1] = gender;
            cleanArray[2] = classification;
            cleanArray[3] = result[0];
            cleanArray[4] = result[3];
            cleanArray[5] = result[5];
            cleanArray[6] = result[6];

            //removing the [ at the start of the date
            cleanArray[4] = cleanArray[4].Substring(1);

            //re-formatting the date so that it can be accepted by machine learning
            var dateString = cleanArray[4];
            var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var newDateString = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            //push each clean array onto the file that has been automatically created at the top
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", cleanArray.Select(v => v.ToString())));
            writer.WriteLine();
        }
        reader.DiscardBufferedData();
        writer.Close();
        reader.Close();    
        }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the format you are want?

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD where as at the minute the date is in DD-MM-YYYY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse your `String` as `DateTime` and then parse the `DateTime` as `String` in the format you want. Something like this.

```
var dateString = "29/Oct/2014:13:36:07";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var newDateString = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

and you'll get

> 2014-10-29

If you need the time as well change the last command to

```
var newDateString = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

and you'll get

> 2014-10-29 13:36:07

For more information have a look at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: As i'll be taking in hundreds of logs i set dateString to element cleanArray[4] which will always be the date field, however when i run the code it gives me an error on the parsing line of code: Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Guess in that line you have a different format. Can you show the line which produces the error?

Comment: This line gives the error: var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: That's obvious. I meant the line of your log which produces the error. In that line the date format will be different. Or even better: what's the exact content of cleanArray[4]? Maybe some blankes at the start or end?

Comment: The format of the date is as seen above in the question - all lines in the log are the same. The only space would be prior to the day after the comma. In this case the exact content of cleanArray[4] is:                           " 29/Oct/2014:13:36:07"

Comment: You should trim your string using clearArray[4].Trim() because that removes all trailing or leading blanks.

Comment: I have found the issue - initially the date had a '[' before it.. however i don't remove this until we are out of the loop. So when implementing the code within the loop the date formate is actually '[29/Oct/2014:13:36:07'.

Comment: I have removed the '[' at the start of the date within the loop using  cleanArray[4] = cleanArray[4].Substring(1); the code now compiles but the date format does not change in the new text file. Any suggestions why this would be? The code in the question has been updated

Comment: You are not updating the cleanArray with the new date. Insert `cleanArray[4] = newDateString;` after you've creater newDateString.

Answer (score 0):

Storing data in string fromat (or retrieving it from that) is tricky. You need the following things:

- the encoding used to store the string in bytes
- the culture format used to store the DateTime
- the timezone the DateTime is applied to.

My first advice is to never store or Transmit DateTimes as strings. Failing that:

You propably do know the encoding of the file. And as this is a log, it will propably keep to the old ASCII settings. Encodings become a lot less relevant under char 127. XML tends to take care of this part for you.

Culture Format is a Problem. By default ToString() and Parse() and all thier variants retrieve the culture format from Windows. And just because they have the same language, does not mean they have the same formats for anything. For example UK and US date formats are *totally different*.
So always pick a fixed one and hardcode it. The Automatic Culture Format only works for direct user input, nothing else.

For the timezone, my advice is to always store and retreive as UTC. Otherwise you have to adapt for the Timezone used by the original writer (wich you might not know and might not be consistent) and your own (wich DateTime.ToString() will do for you).